# RSpec Test Skip Filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm using a gem that should only be run in production.

```
skip_after_filter :kachow_auto_include unless Rails.env.production?
```

How can I test that this is skipped during test and development in RSpec.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stub the method call on Rails.env, then call the action, e.g.:

```
it "should run in production environment" do
  Rails.env.stub(:production?) { true }
  MyController.should_receive(:kachow_auto_include)
  get :action_that_triggers_after_filter
end

it "should not run unless in production" do
  Rails.env.stub(:production?) { false }
  MyController.should_not_receive(:kachow_auto_include)
  get :action_that_triggers_after_filter
end
```

Comment: This looks like it should work but for some reason its not Hmm... interesting. Its not being run even when being stubbed. Odd. I'll continue to check and report back here if I get it working.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that `unless` is only evaluated once on load. You could use a proc instead: `unless: proc { Rails.env.production? }`. The downside to this is you'd be checking every request.